# Access JSON column

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

How can I access values in the `status` and `date` columns stored as JSON?
Please, have a look at an example row below.

`{"1":{"status":true,"date":"2022-03-30"},"3":{"status":true,"date":"2022-03-30"}}`

Comment: Use [JSON_EXTRACT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract), assuming you are using at least MySQL 5.7.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work @BillKarwin.. Would you mind sharing some code?

Comment: Show what you tried. Read the documentation he linked to for the full details.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried many things. The thing here is that I don't have keys as the main part - only "1" and "3" and I don't know how to go about it..

Comment: If you tried many things, can't you post one or two of them? That way we can help you understand what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
set @j = '{"1":{"status":true,"date":"2022-03-30"},"3":{"status":true,"date":"2022-03-30"}}';

select json_extract(@j, '$."1".status') as status;
+--------+
| status |
+--------+
| true   |
+--------+
```

In this case, it may be unexpected that you need to put double-quotes around `"1"` to use it in a JSON path.

Comment: Thanks! I was sure I tried that but I must have messed it...